# My reservation and my passport middle full name My passport only initial

Tags: usa, japan, mobile-apps, swiss, iad

I am plan fly to IAD to Japan beginning Dec 2020. My reservation is full my middle name but my password show only initial. Is this any problem when I fly to Japan? One more question,
Before I travel to Japan, upload it in the United app or go directly to a United ticket counter. Please advise.